# How to detect height of page inside iframe?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a iframe in a page

```
<iframe src="page.aspx" >
```

I don't know how big the thing is going to be. How to get the height? May be jquery would be good here beacuse of browser indifferences.

```
// sth like this. 
currentfr.contentDocument.body.offsetHeight // NS 
currentfr.Document.body.scrollHeight // IE
```

Answer (score 2):

like your code , but you enhance it a bit to avoid errors

```
if (window.innerWidth) { //if innerWidth is defined
      // the standard
      w = fr.width,
      h = fr.height
 }
else if (typeof document.documentElement != 'undefined'
     && typeof document.documentElement.clientWidth !=
     'undefined' && document.documentElement.clientWidth != 0) {
       // IE6
       w = fr.document.documentElement.clientWidth,
       h = fr.document.documentElement.clientHeight
}
```